GeoServer GeoWebCache gives not estimation on truncate operation
I have set a truncate operation on GeoServer.
There are no estimations on the front end.
Is there any way I can estimate how long will the truncate operation take time to complete?


truncate will complete pretty much immediately

This one took 2 hours 17 minutes to truncate 130 GB of data
After completion still 3 GB data was observed in the layer folder
